# Two variables in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to declare multiple variables based on user input and use them all as conditions in a WHERE clause. I have the variables hard set to the values I want right now for testing. I plan on using the `@Well` and `@Analyst` variables in a similar manner in the future. Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @Analysis nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @SQLQuery nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Formation nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Well nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @Analyst nvarchar(50)
SET @Analysis = 'Elemental Analysis'
SET @Formation = 'Bruce'
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT TB_Projects.JobLog#, TB_Projects.ProjName, COUNT(TB_Samples.Sample#) AS [Total Samples]
FROM TB_Projects INNER JOIN TB_Samples ON TB_Projects.JobLog# = TB_Samples.JobLog#
WHERE TB_Samples.['+ @Analysis +'] = 1 AND TB_Projects.Formation ='+@Formation+' GROUP BY TB_Projects.JobLog#, TB_Projects.ProjName'
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

I receive the following error with this code:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Bruce'.

'Bruce' should be the value returned for the column TB_Projects.Formation, it's not a column name. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to wrap Formation value in single quotes:

```
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT TB_Projects.JobLog#, TB_Projects.ProjName, COUNT(TB_Samples.Sample#) AS [Total Samples]
FROM TB_Projects INNER JOIN TB_Samples ON TB_Projects.JobLog# = TB_Samples.JobLog#
WHERE TB_Samples.['+ @Analysis +'] = 1 AND TB_Projects.Formation ='''+@Formation+''' GROUP BY TB_Projects.JobLog#, TB_Projects.ProjName'
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this in the string:

```
TB_Projects.Formation = '+@Formation+'
```

This is turned into:

```
TB_Projects.Formation = Bruce
```

See the problem?  If you printed out the string before you ran it, the problem would probably be obvious.

The simplest solution is:

```
TB_Projects.Formation = '''+@Formation+'''
```

That will add single quotes.

A better solution is to use `sp_executesql` with a parameter for the value.

Comment: Is sp_executesql more efficient because it only runs the query once, and then only changes the parameter for subsequent uses of the sql statement? The way that my query will be changing when fully implemented is based on combobox values selected in a c# user interface. There will be 4 comboboxes that can be changed and the values selected will be stored in a c# variable and passed to sqlserver, then my statement above will execute. The c# variables will be doing the work of updating the parameter values for me, would the sp_executesql method be the best solution in this case? Just curious

Comment: @D.Robertson . . . `sp_executesql` is preferable.  It caches the execution plan.  It helps prevent SQL injection attacks and syntax errors as well.